# Does Node-Redshift supports Copy command (query) to load data from S3 to Redshift?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I wanted to know whether "Node-redshift" module supports Copy From query, to get bulk data from S3 bucket and load it in Redshift?
If not what other options I can use to connect to Redshift and use Copy command.

Comment: was my reply below useful? if so, please accept it so that other will find it useful as well

Answer (score 3):

node-redshift is just a basic javascript client, which will execute what ever query/statement/DML you provide it.

In order to execute a copy command, all you need is to initialize the client and execute the command:

```
var copyCommand = "copy DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME 
                   from 's3://BUCKET_NAME/SOME_PREFIX/' 
                   credentials
                   access_key_id 'AKIA...'
                   secret_access_key 'secret...';"

var Redshift = require('node-redshift');

var client = {
  user: user,
  database: database,
  password: password,
  port: port,
  host: host,
};

var redshiftClient = new Redshift(client, [options]);

redshiftClient.connect(function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
  else{
    redshiftClient.query(copyCommand, [options], function(err, data){
      if(err) throw err;
      else{
        console.log(data);
        redshiftClient.close();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

There are several supported formats for the files stored in the bucket like CSV and PARQUET.
See copy command documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html

Snippet was taken from the official redshift-node page https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redshift, and adjusted for the question above.

There is also the official aws nodejs client https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Redshift.html, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that, but the official client (Provided by AWS)  does not support executing specific queries for redshift.